# Напишите программу для вычисления произведения всех чисел от 1 до N (N! N-факториал). По условию N не больше 10

Tags: c++, циклы, visual-c++

На вход программе подается одно положительное число N, которое не превышает 100. Написать программу которая выводит одно единственное число равное сумме чисел от 1 до N.

Comment: Прошу прощения, а это кому задание?

Comment: Это так просто, что вы не сможете не справиться с этим самостоятельно...

Comment: Если там верхний предел 100, а не 10 ( то есть, нужны "большие длинные числа"), то задача стает чуточку интереснее

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Злые вы...

Вот для факториала:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

int f[] = {1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800};

int main() {
    try {
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        if (n < 0 || n > 10) throw std::out_of_range("Wrong number");
        int res = 1;
        for (int i = n; i--> 0;) res = f[n - i];
        std::cout << res;
        }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
        }
    }
```

Comment: А почему без шаблонов и метапрограммирования? :)

Comment: @Harry Ну хоть один человек понял... У остальных пока ни понимания, ни чувства юмора.

Comment: Не знаю, как не понять, что это просто стёб :) И "аххаах" будет при сдаче этого кода...